# SonarQube(Version 5.4) LDAP Integration plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I've installed the LDAP Integration plugin in SonarQube(Version 5.4) and restarted the server.
I didn't make any changes to config file.
When I try to login, a credential prompt pops up, here I enter the same credentials I use to login to server. But even after this the sonarqube console asks me for a username and a password, this is the sonarqube username and password not the windows one's.

Do I need to make any changes for SonaQube to use windows credentials? or is it just ldap?
Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: Could you please update the question and add the version of SonarQube and LDAP you're using ? Thanks

Comment: Hello,
I was using the earlier version of the Ldap plugin: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin
I do not remember the version exactly.

However now I cannot install the ldap plugin as it says it is not compatible.

Thank you.

Comment: @JohnMiller indeed latest version of LDAP plugin (2.1) requires at least SonarQube 5.6, so why not upgrade? And yes - you need to configure LDAP plugin as described on page http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin in order to use it with Active Directory.

Comment: @Godin If I upgrade and install the LDAP plugin(2.1), will I be required to edit LDAP Configuration or will we able to use windows login without any configuration?

Comment: @JohnMiller I already said that you need to configure LDAP plugin in order to use it with Active Directory. "There is no such thing as a free lunch"